# sqlos.process_killed and sqlserver.lock_released Extended events not firing on SQL 2019 Enterprise

Tags: sql-server-2019, extended-events

I have the following extended event sessions configured (among others).  It seems that all events fire except these two.  In the second session, the "lock_acquired" fires just fine, but the "lock_released" never does. "sqlos.process_killed" seems to never fire at all, even though my server log shows SPIDs being killed. When do these events fire, and how do I trap them?
My goal here is to

1. find out exactly what statement was executing on the killed process and
2. figure out what's holding locks and for how long

script:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Killed] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlos.process_killed(
    ACTION(sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.username))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=ON)
GO

CREATE EVENT SESSION [LCK] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.lock_acquired(SET collect_database_name=(1),collect_resource_description=(1)
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.sql_text)
    WHERE ([package0].[greater_than_uint64]([duration],(0)))),

ADD EVENT sqlserver.lock_released(SET collect_database_name=(1),collect_resource_description=(1)
        ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.sql_text)
        WHERE ([package0].[greater_than_uint64]([duration],(0))))
    ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'LCK',max_file_size=(10))
    WITH (MAX_MEMORY=2048 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=ON)
    GO
```

Comment: I'm not sure lock_released will evever have a `duration>0`  on lock_acquired duration accounts for lock waits, but you never have to wait to release a lock.

Comment: I was kind of suspecting that, actually, so I can try removing that condition from that event.  But process_killed, though, has no condition, and it's still not firing